# Efficiently apply several different operations to a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to do several different operations to many columns of a DataSet, I did it but not in a very efficient way...

As an example, I have this table:

```
|   A  |   B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |
|------|------|------|------|------|
|  1.0 |  1.0 |  1.0 |  2.0 |   a  |
|  2.0 |  1.0 |  1.5 |  5.0 |   a  |
|  3.0 |  1.0 |  2.0 |  3.0 |   b  |
|  1.0 |  2.0 |  2.0 |  6.0 |   a  |
|  2.0 |  2.0 |  3.0 |  4.0 |   b  |
|  3.0 |  2.0 |  4.0 |  2.0 |   b  |
|  1.0 |  3.0 |  5.0 |  5.0 |   b  |
|  2.0 |  3.0 |  6.0 |  1.0 |   a  |
|  3.0 |  3.0 | 10.0 |  2.0 |   a  |
```

And I need to get the following result:

```
# I dont need the A column, the criteria is the B column, apply the mean 
# to the C, the sum to the D and the most frequent on E
|   B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |
|------|------|------|------|
|  1.0 |  1.5 | 10.0 |   a  |
|  2.0 |  3.0 | 12.0 |   b  |
|  3.0 |  7.0 |  8.0 |   a  |
```

Here is my attempt but is extremely slow. My original dataset has 2.000.000 of rows. Transforming it to 130.000 takes more than 30 minutes and I have to apply it three times... this is why I need something more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                   "B":[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], 
                   "C":[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0],
                   "D":[2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0],
                   "E":['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']}) 

print(df)

dict_ds = { 'B' : [], 'C' : [], 'D' : [], 'E' : []}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_ds)

df=df.groupby('B')
for n in df.first().index:
    data    = df.get_group(n)
    partial = data.mean()
    new_C   = partial['C']
    partial = data.sum()
    new_D   = partial['D']
    new_E   = data['E'].mode()[0]
    df2.loc[len(df2)] = (n,new_C,new_D,new_E)

print(df2)
```

---

---

---

---

This part is after getting the solution.
If I apply the operation `unique` to the `agg`:

```
df.groupby('B').agg({
                     'A': 'unique',
                     'C': 'mean',
                     'D': 'sum',
                     'E': lambda x: x.mode()
                     }).reset_index()
```

I have the next result:

```
     B                A    C     D  E
0  1.0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  1.5  10.0  a
1  2.0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  3.0  12.0  b
2  3.0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  7.0   8.0  a
```

But I need to have it in this other way:

```
     A    B     C    D   E
0  1.0  1.0   1.5  10.0  a
1  2.0  1.0   1.5  10.0  a
2  3.0  1.0   1.5  10.0  a
3  1.0  2.0   3.0  12.0  b
4  2.0  2.0   3.0  12.0  b
5  3.0  2.0   3.0  12.0  b
6  1.0  3.0   7.0   8.0  a
7  2.0  3.0   7.0   8.0  a
8  3.0  3.0   7.0   8.0  a
```

Is it possible to have something similar? A very efficent way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_df = df.groupby('B').agg({
                     'C': 'mean',
                     'D': 'sum',
                     'E': lambda x: x.mode()
                            })

>>> new_df

B   C   D       E
1.0 1.5 10.0    a
2.0 3.0 12.0    b
3.0 7.0 8.0     a
```

---

EDIT: For your 2nd question...
I can't guarantee that this will be efficient but it gets what you want done:

```
df_1 = new_df['A'].apply(pd.Series).unstack().reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)
df_1.name = 'A'

df_2 = new_df[[col for col in df.columns if col != 'A']]
df_2.name = 'others'

pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_index = True, right_index = True).reset_index(drop = True)

>>> output

    A   B   C   D       E
0   1.0 1.0 1.5 10.0    a
0   2.0 1.0 1.5 10.0    a
0   3.0 1.0 1.5 10.0    a
1   1.0 2.0 3.0 12.0    b
1   2.0 2.0 3.0 12.0    b
1   3.0 2.0 3.0 12.0    b
2   1.0 3.0 7.0 8.0     a
2   2.0 3.0 7.0 8.0     a
2   3.0 3.0 7.0 8.0     a
```

Comment: Awesome! now it takes one minute and 3 seconds!!

Comment: @Joracosu, glad I could help! I've added a solution to your second problem. I'm too burnt out from work to figure out an "optimal" solution to your second question, but I've added a solution that works.

Comment: I hope Radial Analytics pays you a lot. I am sure you're worth every cent of your salary. It is just impressive. The cumputing time comparing with my solution is now reduced from 25 minutes yo just one minute and a half